# Can a Japanese man use the kamon of their mother officially?

Tags: heraldry, japan

In official contexts, can a male Japanese use the [kamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mon_(emblem)) of their mother?

For example, if the person's father is a commoner, only their mother may have a kamon.

I am hoping for an authoritative answer by someone who is a native Japanese and actually knows, not a guess by a non-Japanese.

Comment: Hi Duncan & welcome. I suspect the answer to this will be "it depends". However, you may be able to get a better answer if you are more specific about the date and region in question, and also what the "official contexts" might be (I don't think kamon are officially regulated).

Comment: By an official contexts I mean a job application or a CV for a government appointment or an application for university. Something where you would get into trouble for showing a bogus kamon.